# Counting Groups with Same Datetime and Comparing Count with Other Groups in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is an extract from a dataframe. For each MarketName there should be two Date/Times as in "Ascot - 12:35 Ascot  22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd" in the extract below. Sometimes data is missing from either the earliest or latest Date/Time (as in "Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs") so I want to count the earliest and latest Date/Times and if the counts are not the same delete all rows for that MarketName.

I am new to Pandas and am struggling to work out how to do it. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Extract:

| Date/Time | MarketName | SelectionName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Girandole (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Doctor Parnassus |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Twilight Twist |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Irish Hill |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Hayedo (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Restitution |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Graystone (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Graystone (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Restitution |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Doctor Parnassus |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Twilight Twist |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Irish Hill |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Girandole (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Hayedo (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Winds Of Fire |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Cat Tiger |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Sussex Ranger |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Didero Vallis |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Le Breuil |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Port Of Mars |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Mr Muldoon |
| 2022-01-22 12:55:03 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Downtown Getaway |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Sussex Ranger |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Mr Muldoon |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Port Of Mars |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Le Breuil |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Downtown Getaway |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Cobolobo |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Defi Sacre |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Winds Of Fire |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Didero Vallis |
| 2022-01-22 13:10:16 | Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs | Cat Tiger |

Expected output:

| Date/Time | MarketName | SelectionName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Girandole (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Doctor Parnassus |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Twilight Twist |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Irish Hill |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Hayedo (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Restitution |
| 2022-01-22 12:20:03 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Graystone (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Graystone (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Restitution |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Doctor Parnassus |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Twilight Twist |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Irish Hill |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Girandole (NR) |
| 2022-01-22 12:35:49 | Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd | Hayedo (NR) |

Comment: How looks expected output?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I just want a dataframe containing the rows with MarketName Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd in this example. Thanks

Comment: Do you need test uniqueness Datetimes per `MarketName/SelectionName` like in `mozway` answer? Or need test number of rows `MarketName/SelectionName` like in my answer?

Comment: I remark than once again you heavily reworked your [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2427a426-7060-48f1-9a2a-7de119501a57/view-source) (that was offtopic) to have something similar to mine 5 minutes after I posted… but whatever I guess this will never change…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) or [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) to get the counts of Date per group, then filter by size if all rows have 2 dates:

```
# count the number of dates per MarketName/SelectionName
# keep the name of the MarketNames that have 2 dates
keep = (df.groupby(['MarketName', 'SelectionName'])['Date/Time']
          .nunique().eq(2)
          .groupby(level='MarketName').all()
        )

# slice
out = df[df['MarketName'].isin(keep[keep].index)]
```

Output:

```
              Date/Time                             MarketName     SelectionName
0   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd    Girandole (NR)
1   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd  Doctor Parnassus
2   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd    Twilight Twist
3   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd        Irish Hill
4   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd       Hayedo (NR)
5   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd       Restitution
6   2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd    Graystone (NR)
7   2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd    Graystone (NR)
8   2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd       Restitution
9   2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd  Doctor Parnassus
10  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd    Twilight Twist
11  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd        Irish Hill
12  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd    Girandole (NR)
13  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd       Hayedo (NR)
```

Intermediate `keep`:

```
MarketName
Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd        True
Ascot - 13:10 Ascot 22nd Jan 3m Hcap Chs    False
Name: Date/Time, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is filter out all `MarketName` if count per `MarketName` and `SelectionName` is not equal `2` - filter `s` for not equal `2`, get first level of `MultiIndex` by [`Index.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.Index.html) and filter in [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with invert mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.groupby(['MarketName', 'SelectionName']).size()
df1 = df[~df['MarketName'].isin(s[s.ne(2)].index.droplevel(1))]
print (df1)
             Date/Time                             MarketName  \
0  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
1  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
2  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
3  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
4  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
5  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
6  2022-01-22 12:20:03  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
7  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
8  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
9  2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
10 2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
11 2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
12 2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   
13 2022-01-22 12:35:49  Ascot - 12:35 Ascot 22nd Jan 1m7f Hrd   

       SelectionName  
0     Girandole (NR)  
1   Doctor Parnassus  
2     Twilight Twist  
3         Irish Hill  
4        Hayedo (NR)  
5        Restitution  
6     Graystone (NR)  
7     Graystone (NR)  
8        Restitution  
9   Doctor Parnassus  
10    Twilight Twist  
11        Irish Hill  
12    Girandole (NR)  
13       Hayedo (NR)
```